# How to make Safari website compatible with iPhone

Tags: html, iphone

I have a website that works fine with safari. As per the requirement I want to make this site accessible through iPhone properly. How can I do this? I'm new to iPhone.

If you give me a example of normal web page source code and its converted code(after making change) for iphone then it will be very helpful for me.

I tried iui library but when I attached its files to my web page it displays nothing. I don't know what to do. Can someone point me in the right direction, or give me a complete example?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="../iui/iui-logo-touch-icon.png" />
<meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="YES" />
<style type="text/css" media="screen">@import "../iui/iui.css";</style>
<script type="application/x-javascript" src="../iui/iui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're new to iPhone, Start by reading some [basic](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/) documentation on the topic.

Then, you can take advantage of Safari's iPhone [meta tags](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html) to make the page look the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebKit](http://webkit.org/) for your devlopment.